# How to Add Facebook like button to iOS application using Webview?

Tags: ios, facebook-like

Right now i am struggling with adding Facebook like button to my App.I referred many sites and even developers.Facebook also not provided proper explanation.They just gave frame for like button. Can any one please help in adding Facebook like button in my App using Webview.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: see this https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView project, it uses the web view to display the like button it might help u ..:)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is from working project:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:URL, @"object", nil];

  if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    if (FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken) {
      [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/og.likes"
                                   parameters:params
                                   HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) { }];
    } else NSLog(@"FBSession.activeSession.accessToken IS NULL");
  }
```

`URL` is the URL of object what you want to like.
There's no code for `completionHandler` block and for FB-authentification, I hope you can do it as you need.

Comment: Thanks dude...suppose if we want to show like button similar to layout button_count attribute means like button with count how to do?

Comment: at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes
 I can read that this og.likes API does not work for pages and photos, any alternative ?

Answer (score 2):

To get count of Likes for some URL you can use this code:

```
NSString *likesRequestURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+total_count,+url+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+=\"%@\"&access_token=%@", URL, FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:likesRequestURL]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:60.0f];

    __block NSString *result = [NSString string];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

                               if (error == nil) {
                                   NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                   SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
                                   result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[[jsonParser objectWithString:jsonString] objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"total_count"]];
                                   [jsonString release];
                               } else {
                                   NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
                               }
                           }];
```

Note. In this case was used SBJSONParser, you can use it or replace by something else, just slightly change corresponding code.

Now you can to create fully customized like-button.

Comment: Ok. In my projects it works good, hope in your it will be nice too :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not right. There is a way to realize Like feature not with `UIWebView` bit with `FBRequestConnection`. If you want to use `UIWebView` - colleague **Shan** gives right answer, but if you want to use another way - let me to know.

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?..if any please tell me dude